# Product images use default value

Tags: magento-1.7, scope, gallery

After changing some data for product inside particular store view, "Label" and "Sort order" fields no longer obtain values from Default Values scope if those values are changed.

I will illustrate the example:

1. This is default scope view:
   [image]
2. Then I change Store View into English and change any data (product name for example).
3. I switch again to Default Values scope and change in images Sort Order.[image]
4. But English view don't obtain this updated value. [image]

   Why there is no option "Use Default Value" for image Label and Sort Order fields? There is just for Base Image, Small Image, ... Is there any way to solve this problem? Or do we need to make any changes twice just because we changed product name?

Answer (score 1):

The scope of the attribute `media_gallery` is `is_global = 1` which means it is global. You can try to change the scope, I don't know what the side effects are:

Just add to your sql update script:

```
$this->updateAttribute(
    Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY,
    'media_gallery',
    'is_global',
    Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE
);
```

Good luck.