# Product Images force default sort value

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, eav

This question has been asked before, but the answer to it which was updating a UAV attribute did not help. [Product images use default value](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9840/product-images-use-default-value)

Is there a way to make all store views always use the default sort order values for it's images ? There is no checkbox, I tried implementing something similar to the other default values, but got lost because there is quite a lot of code for it.

Comment: Do you find a solution? I'm trying to do the same thing with sort order, label and checkbox exclude. Thanks

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/142715)

Answer (score 0):

By default magento doesn't care about resetting rows from **catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value** table. So, I managed to solve this problem by adding an observer after product is saved and by adding a patch in order to add a button or checkbox to gallery.phtml file.

> app/code/local/Namespace/Name/etc/config.xml

```
<catalog_product_save_commit_after>
    <observers>
        <catalog_product_save_commit_after_check_media_use_default>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>namespace_name/observer_resetMediaSortOrder</class>
            <method>execute</method>
        </catalog_product_save_commit_after_check_media_use_default>
    </observers>
</catalog_product_save_commit_after>
```

> app/code/local/Namespace/Name/Model/Observer/ResetMediaSortOrder.php

```
<?php
class Namespace_Name_Model_Observer_ResetMediaSortOrder
{
    /**
     * Execute observer on 'catalog_product_prepare_save' event.
     *
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     * @return Namespace_Name_Model_Observer_CheckMediaSortOrder
     */
    public function execute(Varien_Event_Observer $observer): self
    {
        $params = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams();

        $productId = $params['id'];
        $storeId = $params['store'];
        $useDefault = $params['use_default'];

        if (!in_array('sort_order', $useDefault)) {
            return $this;
        }

        $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
        $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
        $writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');

        // get ids values for media gallery
        $select = $readConnection->select()->from(
            $resource->getTableName('catalog_product_entity_media_gallery'),
            'value_id'
        );
        $select->where('entity_id = ?', $productId);
        $valueIds = $readConnection->fetchCol($select);

        if (empty($valueIds)) {
            return $this;
        }

        // delete media gallery values by conditions
        $writeConnection->delete(
            $resource->getTableName('catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value'),
            ['value_id IN (?)' => $valueIds, 'store_id = ?' => $storeId]
        );

        return $this;
    }
}
```

> app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/helper/gallery.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magento.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magento.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     default_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2006-2018 Magento, Inc. (http://www.magento.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */
?>
<?php
/**
 * Template for block Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Helper_Form_Gallery_Content
 */
?>
<?php
$_block = $this;
/* @var $_block Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Helper_Form_Gallery_Content */
?>
<div id="<?php echo $_block->getHtmlId() ?>" >
    <ul class="messages">
        <li class="notice-msg">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Image type and information need to be specified for each store view.'); ?>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="grid">
        <table cellspacing="0" class="data border" id="<?php echo $_block->getHtmlId() ?>_grid" width="100%">
            <col width="1" />
            <col />
            <col width="70" />
            <?php foreach ($_block->getImageTypes() as $typeId=>$type): ?>
                <col />
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <col width="70" />
            <col width="70" />
            <thead>
            <tr class="headings">
                <th><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Image') ?></th>
                <th><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Label') ?></th>
                <th><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Sort Order') ?></th>
                <?php foreach ($_block->getImageTypes() as $typeId => $type): ?>
                    <th><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($type['label']); ?></th>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                <th><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Exclude') ?></th>
                <th class="last"><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Remove') ?></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="<?php echo $_block->getHtmlId() ?>_list">
            <tr id="<?php echo $_block->getHtmlId() ?>_template" class="template no-display">
                <td class="cell-image"><div class="place-holder" onmouseover="<?php echo $_block->getJsObjectName(); ?>.loadImage('__file__')"><span><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Roll Over for preview') ?></span></div><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/spacer.gif')?>" width="100" style="display:none;" alt="" /></td>
                <td class="cell-label"><input type="text" <?php if($_block->getElement()->getReadonly()):?> disabled="disabled"<?php endif;?> class="input-text" onkeyup="<?php echo $_block->getJsObjectName(); ?>.updateImage('__file__')" onchange="<?php echo $_block->getJsObjectName(); ?>.updateImage('__file__')" /></td>
                <td class="cell-position"><input type="text" <?php if($_block->getElement()->getReadonly()):?> disabled="disabled"<?php endif;?> class="input-text validate-number" onkeyup="<?php echo $_block->getJsObjectName(); ?>.updateImage('__file__')" onchange="<?php echo $_block->getJsObjectName(); ?>.updateImage('__file__')" /></td>
                <?php foreach ($_block->getImageTypes() as $typeId=>$type): ?>
                    <td class="cell-<?php echo $typeId ?> a-center"><input <?php if($_block->getElement()->getAttributeReadonly($typeId)) :?> disabled="disabled" <?php endif;?> type="radio" name="<?php echo $type['field'] ?>" onclick="<?php echo $_block->getJsObjectName(); ?>.setProductImages('__file__')" value="__file__" /></td>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                <td class="cell-disable a-center"><input type="checkbox" <?php if($_block->getElement()->getReadonly()):?> disabled="disabled"<?php endif;?> onclick="<?php echo $_block->getJsObjectName(); ?>.updateImage('__file__')" /></td>
                <td class="cell-remove a-center last"><input type="checkbox" <?php if($_block->getElement()->getReadonly()):?> disabled="disabled"<?php endif;?> onclick="<?php echo $_block->getJsObjectName(); ?>.updateImage('__file__')" /></td>
            </tr>
            <?php if($_block->hasUseDefault()): ?>
                <tr id="<?php echo $_block->getHtmlId() ?>_default">
                    <td><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Use Default Value') ?></td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="a-center">
                        <button id="button_use_default_sort_order" title="If is checked, the global values for sort order will be used." type="button" onclick="toggleCheckboxSortOrder()">
                            <span><span><span>Use default</span></span></span>
                        </button>
                        <input id="use_default_sort_order" class="default-checkbox" name="use_default[]" type="checkbox" value="sort_order" style="display: none;"/>
                    </td>
                    <?php foreach ($_block->getMediaAttributes() as $_attribute): ?>
                        <td class="a-center">
                            <?php if($_block->getElement()->canDisplayUseDefault($_attribute)): ?>
                                <input class="default-checkbox" name="use_default[]" type="checkbox"
                                    <?php if($_block->getElement()->getAttributeReadonly($_attribute->getAttributeCode())):?> disabled="disabled" <?php endif;?>
                                       onclick="<?php echo $_block->getJsObjectName(); ?>.updateUseDefault()"
                                       <?php if($_block->getElement()->usedDefault($_attribute)): ?>checked<?php endif; ?>
                                       value="<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeCode() ?>"
                                />
                            <?php endif ?>
                        </td>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="last">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
            <?php endif ?>
            <tr id="<?php echo $_block->getHtmlId() ?>-image-0">
                <td class="cell-image"><?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('No image') ?></td>
                <td class="cell-label"><input type="hidden" />&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="cell-position"><input type="hidden" />&nbsp;</td>
                <?php foreach ($_block->getImageTypes() as $typeId=>$type): ?>
                    <td class="cell-<?php echo $typeId ?> a-center"><input type="radio" <?php if($_block->getElement()->getAttributeReadonly($typeId)) :?> disabled="disabled" <?php endif;?> name="<?php echo $type['field'] ?>" onclick="<?php echo $_block->getJsObjectName(); ?>.setProductImages('no_selection')" value="no_selection" /></td>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                <td class="cell-disable"><input type="hidden" />&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="cell-remove last"><input type="hidden" />&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            <?php if (!$_block->getElement()->getReadonly()):?>
                <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="100" class="last" style="padding:8px">
                        <?php echo Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Maximum width and height dimension for upload image is %s.', Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image::XML_NODE_PRODUCT_MAX_DIMENSION)); ?>
                        <?php echo $_block->getUploaderHtml() ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tfoot>
            <?php endif;?>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<input type="hidden" id="<?php echo $_block->getHtmlId() ?>_save" name="<?php echo $_block->getElement()->getName() ?>[images]" value="<?php echo $_block->escapeHtml($_block->getImagesJson()) ?>" />
<input type="hidden" id="<?php echo $_block->getHtmlId() ?>_save_image" name="<?php echo $_block->getElement()->getName() ?>[values]" value="<?php echo $_block->escapeHtml($_block->getImagesValuesJson()) ?>" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    var <?php echo $_block->getJsObjectName(); ?> = new Product.Gallery('<?php echo $_block->getHtmlId() ?>', <?php echo $_block->getImageTypesJson() ?>);
    function toggleCheckboxSortOrder()
    {
        var checkUseDefault = document.getElementById('use_default_sort_order');
        var buttonUseDefault = document.getElementById('button_use_default_sort_order');

        if (buttonUseDefault.classList.contains('ok_button')) {
            checkUseDefault.checked = false;
            buttonUseDefault.className = '';
        } else {
            checkUseDefault.checked = true;
            buttonUseDefault.className = 'ok_button';
        }
    }
    //]]>
</script>
```

I put the **gallery.phtml**(with the applied changes) file instead of a patch due to it's size, but is better to make a patch instead on changing this file.

With the above code every time when you save a product on a store you can click the new button to reset the 'sort order' in order to apply the global values(from Default Values store view).